# How to load ImageURL into Bitmap and to add it to ViewPager Collection in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

i followed this URL http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

here it works with Textview.

```
         TextView tv = new TextView(cxt);    
         tv.setText("Bonjour PAUG " + position); 
         tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);   
         tv.setTextSize(30);         
         ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv,0); 
         return tv;
```

..............................................................

But i have set of imageURLs and then i need to load it to Bitmap and then i need to add this to ViewPager.....ANY IDEAS!!!

```
     public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position)
     {  
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext() .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            int resId = 0;    
         try
             {
                String saveimg= urls[position];
                String url1 = saveimg ;
                URL ulrn = new URL(url1);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                if (null != bmp)
                {
                    ImageView Imgview=new ImageView(cxt);
                    Imgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(Imgview, 0);  
                    int i=0;
                    return Imgview;  


                }
                else

                    System.out.println("The Bitmap is NULL");

               }

             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 int i=0;
             }
```

Comment: Hi, should you provide your solution? Thanks

Comment: @markov00 : what you need to know

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader...Hope this will help you..let me know if u need more about the pager

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)